# Problems with Mouse Hover/Image Swap

Tags: jquery, html, css

In this JSFiddle, I'm trying to do a simple mouseover an image, it changes image, mouse off, the image changes back. But for some reason I'm not seeing the problem in the code.

http://jsfiddle.net/gmULU/2/

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
 $('.normalClassName').click(function () {
$(this).addClass('hoverClassName');
}, function () {
$(this).removeClass('hoverClassName');
});
});
```

There seems to be a "tiling" problem where the original image tiles.  See the JSFiddle.

Also if anyone can tell me what code do I need to add, to get it where I can have a mouse click on the 2nd image and out appears to the right another image to where I can click on that 3rd image to go to a link.  Thanks

Comment: You dont even need javascript, use css, hover class, here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Please [don't use w3schools](http://w3fools.com/) as reference. Instead, look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:hover).

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want it to happen at `mouseover` or `hover`, why use `.click()`?
2. `.click()` doesn't have a `handlerOut` attached to it.

If you only need to switch the image(and not the background) as you state in your question(I've overlooked your code) then you can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.normalClassName').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('img').attr( 'src', 'http://creativebits.org/files/500px-Apple_Computer_Logo.svg_.png' );
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('img').attr( 'src', 'http://www.applegazette.com/wp-content/uploads/apple-logo.jpg' );
    });
});
```

Here's the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gmULU/5/) to working fiddle update.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to only swap from an image to another you can do this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="normalClassName"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.normalClassName {
    width: 512px;
    height: 512px;
    background: transparent url('http://www.applegazette.com/wp-content/uploads/apple-logo.jpg') top left no-repeat;
}

.normalClassName:hover {
     background: transparent url('http://creativebits.org/files/500px-Apple_Computer_Logo.svg_.png') top left no-repeat;
}
```

In this way, the background will swap from an image to another when mouse is hovering, but remeber to use images of same size.

Here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ragnarokkr/Eqxb9/) to test. As you can see the images have different sizes and the effect is *ugly*.